# Mapstruct implementation is not generating copying commands

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

Mapstruct suddenly stopped generating implementation class correctly.
Here is the implementation class generated by MapStruct now.
The first method returns an empty pessoaDto. It should copy all attributes from Pessoa p. Both classes have the same attribute names.

```
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor",
    date = "2020-12-06T09:51:30-0300",
    comments = "version: 1.4.1.Final, compiler: javac, environment: Java 11.0.9 (Oracle Corporation)"
)
@Component
public class PessoaMapperImpl implements PessoaMapper {

    @Override
    public PessoaDto pessoaParaDto(Pessoa p) {
        if ( p == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        PessoaDto pessoaDto = new PessoaDto();

        return pessoaDto;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PessoaDto> listaPessoaParaDto(List<Pessoa> lista) {
        if ( lista == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        List<PessoaDto> list = new ArrayList<PessoaDto>( lista.size() );
        for ( Pessoa pessoa : lista ) {
            list.add( pessoaParaDto( pessoa ) );
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is the build configuration in pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Here is the MapStruct interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PessoaMapper {

    PessoaMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(PessoaMapper.class);

    PessoaDto pessoaParaDto(Pessoa p);

    List<PessoaDto> listaPessoaParaDto(List<Pessoa> lista);

}
```

Comment: Post your MapStruct interface, your build configuration, and any Java files that MapStruct is generating (in someplace like `target/generated-sources`).

Comment: Share both the classes along with Mapper and its implementation.

Comment: Are you using Lombok by any chance?